# adreno profiler for Linux/Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, gpu

I downloaded the adreno profiler for Linux from here 
https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/maximize-hardware/mobile-gaming-graphics-adreno/tools-and-resources

The tar file which I downloaded does not have any linux executables.

It only has .exe files. I tried to run it using WINE, but was without any luck.

Did anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run it with mono.

```
$ sudo apt-get install mono-complete
$ mono AdrenoProfiler.exe
```

Would be cool if they just included a simple run.sh as a lot of people seem to be having this issue.